# How to add button handler in Scala Play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl

I'm using scala play framework + scala template engine for front end. How can I add button handler? I need to call some function when clicking on it.

```
<body>
    <p>Database interface<br />
        <textarea style="margin: 0px; height: 193px; width: 533px;" cols="40" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Select" /> <input type="submit" value="Insert" />  <input type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no special button handlers. You can write it in Javascript or plain HTML. The only trick thing is to get a link the server function. You can get the link automatically by [reverse routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting#reverse-routing).

For example you have the route

```
GET     /count                      controllers.CountController.count
```

Then you can get the link by calling `controllers.routes.CountController.count` in your code.

In the template engine, link:

```
<a href="@controllers.routes.CountController.count">Count</a>
```

Plain HTML button:

```
<form action="@controllers.routes.CountController.count">
  <input type="submit" value="HTML only" />
</form>
```

Button with Javascript:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="location.href='@controllers.routes.CountController.count';" value="Javascript" />
```

If you need some special thing on the client side to process then you need to write your own code in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was some OOB button handler in Twirl.

Comment: if `@controllers.routes.CountController.count` took a variable, say from a textarea, how would you pass that variable?

Comment: You could not pass that variable. `@controllers.routes.CountController.count` is processed on the server, before it returns the HTML to the client. The data in the `textarea` are on the client.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Scala/Play/Twirl that would handle button clicks, the simplest approach would be to use [jQuery .click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: interesting, could you substantiate your answer with a source? I had this issue a few...minutes ago and was wondering why the `<input type="button" value="Register" href="@CSRF(routes.MyApp.register())/>"` was not opening my register page

Comment: @KGCybeX If you want to use "@CSRF(routes.MyApp.register())" in an javascript ajax call with parameters from javascript, how do you put them in? F.x. in some javascript: var type = 1; ...  $.ajax({ url: "@CSRF(routes.MyApp.register(type))", ... });. Here the compiler would think that "type" comes from scala instead of javascript.